# WARNING: Ipopt finished with status Invalid_Number_Detected

Tags: optimization, julia

Trying to solve a large NLP. the code is approximately as follows:

```
using JuMP
using Ipopt
m=Model(solver=IpoptSolver())
@variable(m,k,start=1.2)
....
@NLparameter(m,α==0.28)
.....
@NLconstraint(m,cons1, 0<=((6.376151933328191*θ_1k^2*θ_3c -....<=0)
......
@NLobjective(m,Max,1.0)
solve(m)
```

With the first set of start values (some negative and other positive) for the variables, I receive the following error message:

> **WARNING: Ipopt finished with status Invalid_Number_Detected**

When I alter the values of initials (all positive), I receive the following message instead

> **Warning: Cutting back alpha due to evaluation error**.

Please, what could be the meaning of such behavior? Is there an Ipopt option that could help to solve the problem? Thanks for helping

Comment: What should ```@NLconstraint(m,cons1, 0<=((6.376151933328191*θ_1k^2*θ_3c -....<=0)``` do? Am i reading correctly and you try to bound some expression between 0 and 0? There is even a bracket missing, or two, right? Add som reproducable code to get people to help you. And always do some web-search for these errors as there are tons of resources.

Comment: It is a system of 21 NL equations with 21 unknowns, I want to solve. You can read the line as `@NLconstraint(m,cons1, 0<=f(x)<=0)`. Please, the involved NL equations are pretty large, that's why I used the ....

Comment: Add bounds to make sure functions can be evaluated everywhere. If needed add extra variables (e.g. rewrite `log(x-y)` to `log(z), z>=0.01, z=x-y`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, there is no such operation in the involved functions that could lead to NaN or Inf, hoping I am getting you right. I even came across [this](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/ticket/187), describing exactly the same behavior, but when using Ipopt in Matlab. Unfortunately, I am not getting the point in. Please, a look at could help you to help me. Thanks

Comment: Just to add more info. The behavior is pretty unpredictable. With different all positive initials guesses, I have: `*EXIT: Invalid number in NLP function or derivative detected*`, sometimes `*Restoration failed*`, sometimes `*Cutting back alpha due to evaluation error*`. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's pretty much a black-box for us not seeing the code (and not my expertise). But would it not just be better to formulate this as classic least-squares problem: so instead constraint ```0<=f(x)<=0```, putting this into the objective ```min norm(f_0, f_1, ...)```. Compare with least-squares for well-defined and ill-conditioned matrices. I'm afraid ipopt is really struggling to create something feasible here, although these error-messages look a bit puzzling.